# How to find the sum of a finite number of increasing fractional powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, exponential-sum

It is easy to show
$\quad\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^i}=\dfrac{1}{n-1}\quad$
e.g.
$$\quad\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^i}=\dfrac{1}{1}\quad$  $\quad\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{3^i}=\dfrac{1}{2}\quad$  $\quad\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{4^i}=\dfrac{1}{3}\quad$$

and so on but what about summing to a finite power $\,n?$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \dfrac{1}{n^i}=???$$

I have developed a method of deriving formulas for the sums of integer powers of any degree but this is a case of proper fractions and it is the powers that are the increasing integers in this sum. I just don't know how to approach this. Any suggestions.

$\textbf{Update:}$

Thanks to @Feng, I have been able to show that
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{i=1}^{k} q^i&= \dfrac{q(1-q^k)}{1-q}
, q=\dfrac{1}{n}
 \implies  \dfrac{\frac{1}{n}(1-\frac{1}{n^k})}{1-\frac{1}{n}} 
 =\frac{n^k-1}{n^k(n - 1)}, \,n\ge2
 \end{align*}
and Wolfram confirms that this formula works. Thank you.

Comment: [Geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)? They have summation formula: $$\sum_{i=1}^k q^i=\frac{q(1-q^k)}{1-q}$$ for $q\neq1$.

Comment: @Feng Liet $\,i\,$ be negative. How do we find finite sums of negative powers ?

Comment: You can take $q=\frac1n (n\geq2)$ in your case, so they are POSITIVE powers of $q$. Or $$\sum_{i=-k}^{-1}q^i=\sum_{j=1}^k\left(\frac1q\right)^j.$$

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to derive the finite sum of fractional powers formula (above) directly, using 3 terms to infer the workings of any finite number of terms:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{3} \dfrac{1}{x^i}
&=\dfrac{1}{x^1}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{x^3}\\ \\
&=\dfrac{x^2}{x^3}+\dfrac{x}{x^3}+\dfrac{1}{x^3}\\\\
&=\dfrac{x^2+x+1}{x^3}\\ \\
&=\dfrac{(x^2+x+1)}{x^3}\cdot\dfrac{(x-1)}{(x-1)}\\ \\
&=\dfrac{x^3-1}{x^3(x-1)}\\ \\
\implies
\sum_{i=1}^{k} \dfrac{1}{x^i}
&=\dfrac{x^k-1}{x^k(x-1)}
\end{align*}